# Utility for Refilling an Account on A certain Schedule

Tags: paypal, google-api, android-pay, banking, tasker

Say I have several accounts with Generic Bank. One account is the Master account and all the others are specific budgetary purpose accounts - like one for eating out or for gas. For any given time period theres a certain amount of money I have budgeted for each purpose - say $7 a day for eating out and $20 every three days for gas. After the given time period expires, I want the account refilled from whatever value it currently sits at, back up to the specified amount.

The idea is to passively manage my spending by limiting access and to keep me from thinking that I have more money to spend on a given purpose than I really have. For an example of the last case, say I put the whole months allotment into the gas account all at once. Anytime I checked that account's balance it would return a much larger number than what my actual time-period based allotment would be. Because of the association with the larger number and my inability to keep track of purchases or math in my head, it's very likely that I'd err on the side of making the purchase when in actuality I'm spending the money too fast.

**Are there any services, software, or other utilities that can do bank transfers like this natively? Failing that, are there any money moving services, like Paypal or Google Wallet, that can accept add-on programs built to do this?** I took a cursory look at the Paypal and Wallet APIs but, in addition to reminding of how out of my depth I was (I've never done anything involving APIs or banking), everything I saw was about person to person payments and not necessarily about account to account transfers. But then again, I'm not sure what the practical difference between the two is.

Answer (score 0):

There are several banks who provide these types of services. I, personally, would advise against doing it with Tasker unless your bank specifically supports it, since it opens you up to glitches and security risks.